# OCMock does not recognize called selector

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, ocmock

I'm struggling with a testcase that uses OCMock. So far I used OCMock in a few projects and it always work as i thought. I have the following method that tests that `[self setNeedsDisplay]` is called when I set a property called `image`.

```
- (void)testSetTapColorCallsDrawRect 
{
    SMColorButton *button = [[SMColorButton alloc] initWithImage:nil];
    id mock = [OCMockObject partialMockForObject:button];

    // Exptect setNeedsDisplay. 
    [[mock expect] setImage:OCMOCK_ANY];
    [[mock expect] setNeedsDisplay];

    button.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Button.png"];

    [mock verify];
}
```

And the setter for the `image` property looks like this.

```
- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)anImage
{
    // Set the image if it changed.
    if (anImage != image) {
        image = anImage;
        [self setNeedsDisplay];
    }
}
```

You can see `[self setNeedsDisplay]` is called in the setter. But when I run the tests I get the following error:

`OCPartialMockObject[SMColorButton]: expected method was not invoked: setNeedsDisplay`

It looks as if the method was not called. But if I set a breakpoint the the setter method, it stops and shows me that the line was executed by the application.

Can you help me out? I don't see what I'm doing wrong...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're mocking the method you're testing, `setImage:`. That expectation intercepts the call, so it never follows the code path in the class under test. Try changing your test to:

```
- (void)testSetTapColorCallsDrawRect 
{
    SMColorButton *button = [[SMColorButton alloc] initWithImage:nil];
    id mock = [OCMockObject partialMockForObject:button];    
    [[mock expect] setNeedsDisplay];

    button.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Button.png"];

    [mock verify];
}
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you I didn't think about that but it's completely logical. OCMock just checks if the method was called. The test now fails/runs as expected. Thank you!